# Программа застревает при считывании ответа от TcpClient, при stream.Read

Tags: c#, tcp

```
var client = new TcpClient("2ip.ru", 443);
var stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream());
stream.AuthenticateAsClient("2ip.ru");
string request = "GET https://2ip.ru HTTP/1.1" + Environment.NewLine +
"Host: 2ip.ru" + Environment.NewLine +
"Connection: keep-alive" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
byte[] requestBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
stream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
int bytes;
do
{
    bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
} while (bytes != 0);
```

Ответ выводит до конца, но из последнего цикла выбраться не может

Comment: [The implementation will block until at least one byte of data can be read, in the event that no data is available. Read returns 0 only when there is no more data in the stream and no more is expected (such as a closed socket or end of file).](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netframework-4.8) то есть это блокирующее чтение, вы ждете следующего сообщения,э.

Comment: Подозреваю, что застряет в stream.Read. Вы посылаете Connection: keep-alive и сервер может держать соединение открытым, даже когда все данные ушли. HTTP/1.1 тоже по умолчанию все keep-alive, если не сказано иное

Comment: @vitidev прочитать из заголовка длину тела, и от этой длинны отталкиваться?

Comment: Ну если топорно, то HTTP/1.0, Connection: close. Если не поможет, то использовать Content-Length или использовать HttpClient ( у вас ведь http, так зачем TcpClient)

Comment: @vitidev на более низком уровне хочу попробовать